# C# Settings File: Why do I have to use Settings.Default?

Tags: c#, settings, settings.settings

I'm just wondering why it's `Settings.Default.<mysetting>` instead of just `Settings.<mysetting>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply put: because `Settings` is a class, and the properties are *instance* properties. So you need an instance, and the default way of creating an instance is through the `Default` property.

The obvious followup question is why the properties aren't just static to start with... and I surmise that the answer is that it's useful to be able to create settings in ways *other* than with the default settings load/save approach... for example, loading them from a database, or from a different file path.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to use Settings.Default.CompanyName when Settings.CompanyName can be created as Property returning the instance's value.